# Цикл внутри цикла wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, циклы, шорткод, acf

Создана произвольная таксономия для каталога товаров и с помощью плагина ACF тип поля Relationship сделан вывод этих товаров в нужных местах. Появилась необходимость вывести эти посты внутри цикла для этого написал шорткод, но он отказывается работать внутри записи, если вставлять прямо в .php все работает.
Подскажите в чем моя ошибка? Шорткод выводит данные в начало поста, в независимости от того где его разместить.
Код шорткода

```
    function true_mycode_func( $atts ){

        extract( shortcode_atts( array(  
                          'posts_per_page'  => 20,
                          'post_type'       => 'card',
                          'post__in'            => $ids,
                          'post_status'     => 'any',
                          'orderby'         => 'post__in', 
        ), $atts ) );  
        // создаем запрос для выборки типов записей card 
        $ids = get_field('catalog_card', false, false);
        $loop =  new WP_Query(array(
                          'posts_per_page'  => 20,
                          'post_type'       => 'card',
                          'post__in'            => $ids,
                          'post_status'     => 'any',
                          'orderby'         => 'post__in',
                      ));
        // В цикле проходим по записям и создаем HTML-структуру.  
        if($loop){  
            while ($loop->have_posts()){  
                 $loop->the_post();  
                 $output .= get_template_part( 'template-parts/single', 'card' );  
            }  
        }  
        wp_reset_postdata();                  
        return $output;  
        }
    add_shortcode( 'mycode', 'true_mycode_func' );
```

Заранее спасибо!

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ. Даже если ни чего не выводить return в коде, и вставить [mycode] в запись, цикл все равно выводится в начале записи ???

Answer (score 2):

После окончания цикла в вашем шорткоде надо выполнить

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Эта функция возвращает переменные цикла в правильное состояние. Подробнее [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_reset_postdata).

И еще одна проблема - если у вас тема twentyseventeen, то она использует основной цикл WordPress внутри `/template-parts/single`. Вам надо использовать для вывода контента поста шаблон без цикла: `wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/template-parts/post/content.php`

Comment: Да спасибо, действительно забыл сбросить, но ни чего не изменилось к сожалению. Код поправил

Comment: Поясню в чем проблема, после вставки шорткода в запись и попытке сохранить, заканчивается с ошибкой, хоть и сохраняется. В записи шорткод выводится не в том месте где стоит, а в начале записи.

Comment: Я бы вынес wp_reset_postdata() в самый конец, перед return. И еще одно соображение добавил в ответ.

Comment: А причем тут сохранение? При сохранении записи в базу пишется только текст [...] никакой ваш код не вызывается

Comment: Вот это и странно, если убрать шорткод все проходит нормально, тема culture. Только что посмотрел, при сохранении url записи обрезается до  post.php т.е. дальше ни чего нет, а должно быть post.php?post=1&action=edit

Comment: Где слово "сохранение" в вашем вопросе? Какое отношение к циклам оно имеет? Мы здесь не можем обсуждать все проблемы разработки вашего сайта. Про сохранение - задайте другой вопрос

Comment: С сохранением понятно, буду разбираться. А вот вопрос почему созданный шорткод выводится всегда в начало записи не зависимо от того куда его вставить

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался с данной проблемой, может кому то будет полезно. Как писалось в вопросе код шорткода рабочий, но вызывается странно, постоянно в верху записи, как оказалось это все из за разметки

```
$output .= get_template_part( 'template-parts/single', 'card' );
```

т.е. я брал обычный файл и подключал его, но такая разметка на сколько я понял не правильно воспринимается, в связи с чем решено попробовать другой вариант

```
$output .= '<div class="type-post hentry"><h2 class="entry-title"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';  
$output .= '<div class="entry-content">'.get_the_excerpt().'</div>'; 
$output .= '<div class="entry-content">'.acf_failed_img.'</div></div>';
```

Итого готовый код выглядит так

```
function true_mycode_func( $atts ) {
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                ''limit' => '10',
            ),
            $atts
        )
    );

    // создаем запрос для выборки типов записей card 
    $ids = get_field('catalog_card', false, false);
    $loop =  new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page'  => $limit,
        'post_type'       => 'card',
        'post__in'        => $ids,
        'post_status'     => 'any',
        'orderby'         => 'post__in',
    ));

    // В цикле проходим по записям и создаем HTML-структуру.  
    if ($loop) {
        while ($loop->have_posts()) {
            $loop -> the_post();
            $single_card = get_field('single_card');
            $acf_failed_img = $single_card['img']['sizes']['cat_card-thumb'];
            $acf_failed_alt = $single_card['img']['alt'];
            $output .= '<div class="type-post hentry"><h2 class="entry-title"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
            $output .= '<div class="entry-content">'.get_the_excerpt().'</div>';
            $output .= '<img src="'.acf_failed_img.'" alt="'.acf_failed_alt.'"/></div>';
            // ну и так далее воссоздаем нужную HTML разметку
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;  
}
add_shortcode( 'mycode', 'true_mycode_func' );
```

теперь все работает как нужно!